# Why does my website load a white with back text page before loading my website?

Tags: reactjs, performance, material-ui, netlify

I just published my portfolio using netlify and everytime i refresh the page I see a milisecond of all the text that is on my page and then the css kicks in with the material ui components. Is it a cache issue? I am not too sure how to fix this problem.

website: https://www.jacktkay.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is because the CSS is taking longer to load than the HTML. You can try to combine CSS rules such as:

```
margin-top: 5px;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 10px;
```

Can be combined into

```
margin: 5px 10px 0 10px;
```

You could also try to use a CSS minify tool